# why i cannot use chain expression in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

This don't work:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random(10).sort()
```

this is ok:

```
Z = np.random.random(10)
Z.sort()
```

Please tell me why the chain expression don't work in Numpy.

Comment: Both of these snippets don't throw an error. What do you expect the first one to do?

Comment: I want to generate a random array with length 10, then sort the array. The first snippets don't give the right result, but the second will

Comment: `*.sort()` is a method.  So the first attempt doesn't create data, it is a pointer to a method, namely "the action of creating random numbers and then sorting them".  So instead of the data you want, you have the method to get the data you want.  And that method isn't even right as it mutuates data in-place and you haven't assigned a place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `list.sort`, `numpy.ndarray.sort` sorts in-place, meaning that it *mutates* the array and then returns `None`.

`help(numpy.ndarray.sort)` ->

> sort(...)
>       a.sort(axis=-1, kind='quicksort', order=None)
>       Sort an array, in-place.

With

```
np.random.random(10).sort()
```

you won't see any output in the REPL because `None` is not displayed.
(Even if this line produced a value other than `None`, which it does not, it would be pretty pointless since you don't assign any name.)

In the second example, you create an array `Z` and then sort it, which works as expected.